# How to open vmdk files in VMware?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmdk

I have lots of .vmdk files:

- blabla-s001.vmdk
- blabla-s002.vmdk
- blabla-s003.vmdk

How do I open them with VMware?

Comment: Hi, have you read the VMWare docs at all? This seems like the kind of basic question the documentation would cover.

Comment: Maybe your question is "how to I import lots of VMWare images as the same time". Do you need to batch import images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From VMware workstation, either:

- File
- Open
- Browse to the directory containing the virtual machine's files (both the vmdk and the vmx files)
- Open the `.vmx` file.

Done. You now have the virtual machine in your setup.

Alternatively, if you just want to browse what is in the disk files without starting the vm:

From VMware workstation:

- File
- Map virtual disks
- Map
- Browse
- Browse to the directory containing the files.
- Select the disk file
- [OK]

Done.

[image]

Comment: oh my ... didn't see that file sitting at the end in finder ... thank you!

Comment: if its someone like me who came after downloading only the vmdk file, then create a new vm by choosing I'll install OS later. Choose the OS whose vmdk you have downloaded. Choose "store virtual disk as a single file". When you are done replace the vmdk you downloaded with the one that is created. Start the vm. enjoy!